# If earth had another moon and rings?

Tags: earth-like, moons, planetary-rings

I know this is probably a lousy question, and I'm sorry if it is. What if Earth had another moon closer than Luna and rings in between the two moons? How would Earth's culture and environment be affected by rings and two moons on border patrol? I understand that this would probably not be possible, because tidal forces will destroy the rings, but what if? Maybe Luna II's tidal forces will balance out Luna's (***and Sol's***) and nothing will happen? This is a lot to ask.

Comment: I said I'm sorry if it was a bad question.

Comment: The problem is that you made the question much too broad.  There are so many, many ways that Earth's culture could be different.  And it is also likely that it might be pretty much the same.

Comment: You might be interested into the Related Questions section on the right panel, particularly [If Earth had rings would humans have discovered it wasn't flat sooner?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39602) and [How to naturally maintain a Earth-sized Planetary Ring System and the possible periodic bombardment that can ensue?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/44779)

Comment: When I originally thought of this, I mainly wanted to know how the two moons would break the rings, the other questions are just extra.

Comment: There is a video called [If Earth Had Rings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CItDiuBWP5I) that explains most of the things.

Comment: See *Roche Limit*.  Rings inside, moons outside.  You can’t have moons closer than rings.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/23452/809

Comment: Typically we can't provide good answers to questions about culture, sociology, etc.  Therefore, they tend to be closed.  If you instead are more interested in what they'd look like or how the physics might work, many people here could answer that very accurately.  However, as the above comments point out, there are many similar questions available.  Read those.  If they do not answer your questions, feel free to edit this one to ask any remaining questions you might have.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that the culture on earth would be deeply affected. Heres why:

1) RELIGION — the moon has played a large part in religions worldwide for a long time now. Think Greek goddess Artemis, or her Roman equivalent, Diana. If there were suddenly two moons, those  mythologies would immediately be altered, and drastically. There would have to be new myths to explain the rings, too.

2) TIDES — with two moons and rings, the tides would be unpredictable and dangerous, resulting in sailing being greatly intensified. It would be too risky to use boats on the ocean too much, so trade would be inhibited and all of general civilization would probably be set back at least a century

3) APOLLO MISSIONS — pretty much speaks for itself.

EDIT:

4) MOON RINGS — the moons could collect material from the rings and have their own visible rings. They’d also probably have a lot more craters in them from impacts with the rings.

Comment: Apollo missions: lol.

Comment: Also, literature would be affected a lot: if a single moon has inspired so much poetry then imagine how much more it would be if there were two of them!

Comment: With rings on top of it! Who knows what craziness might arise!